# Umbraco Disable NuCache Database Composer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, umbraco

i have a problem (in log file):
"An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.","@l":"Error","@x":"System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '\server\root\hostname\htdocs\folder\umbraco\Data\TEMP\NuCache\NuCache.Content.db' because it is being used by another process."
So in Umbraco doc advise to implement:

In appsettings.json

```
    "Umbraco": {
      "CMS": {
        "NuCache": {
          "BTreeBlockSize": 4096
        }
      }
    }
```

```
public class DisableNuCacheDatabaseComposer : IComposer
        {
            public void Compose(IUmbracoBuilder builder)
            {
                var settings = new 
         Umbraco.Cms.Infrastructure.PublishedCache.PublishedSnapshotServiceOptions
                {
                    IgnoreLocalDb = true
                };
                builder.Services.AddSingleton(settings);
            }
         }
```

How and where can i use/invoke the Compose method of DisableNuCacheDatabaseComposer ? In Startup file? In Program file?

Thanks in advance and have a nice day

Comment: Studying Umbraco, it is not necessary to call the composer as the system automatically accesses the class and reads its code.

Comment: When Umbraco starts up it looks for all classes inherited from "IComposer", so it just has to be in the project somewhere. I always put my Composers in a folder called "Composers", that way they dont get forgotten about.